# RSpec set session object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, object, rspec

I'm trying to set a session object from my controller spec.

```
it 'use invalid coupon' do
  session[:coupon] = 'abcd'      
  Service.any_instance.stub(:validate_coupon).with(session[:coupon]).and_return('abcd')

  get :index
  expect(flash[:coupon__notice]).to be nil
end
```

but when I inspect the session, instead of a @coupon object, I get a @data that contains the string 'coupon', and test fails.

Comment: What does `validate_coupon` do? Didn't you mean to do - `Service.any_instance.stub(:validate_coupon).with(:coupon).and_return('abcd')`? As it is, it is actually `Service.any_instance.stub(:validate_coupon).with('abcd').and_return('abcd')`, since `session[:coupon]` is `'abcd'`...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is explained in the [Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) in section 4 "Functional Tests for your Controllers. The `get` action takes a params hash *and* a session hash, e.g.:

```
get(:show, {'id' => "12"}, {'user_id' => 5})
```

You should be able to pass in `nil` for the params hash in your example, then pass in your desired session parameters:

```
get :index, nil, {coupon: 'abcd'}
```

I recommend a thorough reading of the Rails guide for anyone using RSpec for Rails testing. `rspec-rails` leverages the existing Rails test classes, a point which is not made very clear in the `rspec-rails` docs.

Comment: You are totally right! I skipped some parts from the Rails Guide. Do you know the difference between the suggested method and assigning explicitly some value to the session like session[:coupon]='abcd'. Just because sometimes seems to work too.

Answer (score 54):

In Rails 5+, if you are using `ActionController::TestCase` session is passed as a keyword arg.

Setting params and session would look like:

```
get(:show, params: {'id' => "12"}, session: {'user_id' => 5})
```

Setting only the session would look like,

```
get(:show, session: {'user_id' => 5})
```

If you are using `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`, which is the new default for for controller tests, you are **not** able to set the session variables and should set them by walking your test through the login flow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @HParker ;)

Comment: It looks like this only works in an ActionController::TestCase, which is no longer the default parent class for controller specs.  The default is now ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest, which does not expose a method of setting session variables, and [DHH recommends making an actual request to imitate logging in with the interface](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23386#issuecomment-178013357), (as is the convention of an integration test).

Comment: Thanks @mltsy! I updated the answer to include info about when your base class is `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. Let me know if I got any of the details wrong.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use @request object like

```
@request.session['coupon'] = 'abcd'
```

Comment: glad that it was useful! @Haider

Comment: Not before the request has been made

Answer (score 3):

In controller specs you can also do:

```
request_params = { city: 'Bomet', code: '023' }
session_params = { taxes_paid: 'No' }
```

Then in your spec you can do:

```
get :edit, params: request_params, session: session_params
```

In your functionality, you can access your session with `session[:taxes_paid]`

Comment: The `get :edit, request_params, session_params` line raises the following error: `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)` with Rails 6 and rspec 3.9.

Comment: Updated answer to take params and session keys

Comment: This may work in controller specs but not in request specs. Using rspec-rails 5.1.0, I get `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :session`

Comment: The question does state that the OP is using controller spec