# Testing Admin Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rspec, admin, factory-bot

Authentication is completely made from scratch and the goal is to test everything while I'm at it. I created an administrative dashboard that only an admin has access to but my test is giving me the following error:

```
  1) Admin::DashboardController GET index with correct credentials returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
```

From reading questions that stem from the same error. It appears that it might be `current_user` that is actually returning nil, yet when I try to set the current_user's session to the `user` variable, I'm still getting the same error. I've also tried stubbing the `current_user` and still getting the same error.

Here is the spec:

**dashboard_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe "GET index" do
    before(:each) do
        allow(controller).to receive(:require_auth)
        allow(controller).to receive(:current_user)
end

context "with correct credentials" do
    it "returns http success" do
      user = create(:admin)
      session[user_id: user]
      get :index 
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
end
```

**dashboard_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_admin
    before_action :require_auth

  def index
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  add_flash_types :success, :error

  private
  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :logged_in?

  def logged_in?
    current_user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end

  def require_auth
    unless current_user
      session[:target] = request.fullpath
      redirect_to new_user_session_path, 
        notice: "You must be logged in to access that page."
    end
  end

  def require_admin
    unless current_user.admin?
      redirect_to :back, 
        notice: "Access denied."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you are using Devise, it provides you with helpers that you can use for logging in and logging out in the controller. [test helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers)

Comment: I'm building my authentication from scratch as a learning experience for both how authentication/authorization works as well as TDD/BDD.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should store user.id instead of user in your session:

```
context "with correct credentials" do
it "returns http success" do
  user = create(:admin)
  get :index, nil, {user_id: user.id}
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
end
end
```

Also, as a side note, `redirect_to :back` only works when browser sends information about referrer, but it's not always true. I.e. firefox in privacy mode does not.

Comment: Thank for the response as well as the side note on `redirect_to :back`. Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same error..

Comment: @Shroy, in this case I suggest trying different method for setting session. See chosen answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451969/rspec-set-session-object

Comment: Tried many of those combinations and still getting the error. What's interesting is I added `expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(user.id)` after setting the `session[user_id: user.id` to see what it output and got this error: `expected: 2 
            got: nil (compared using ==)`

Comment: @Shroy, well, at least we know why current_user returns nil. That's because session is also nil for some reason. Could it be the stubs in `before` block causing this? Did you try to remove them?

Comment: from what I've learned, the correct syntax for stubbing a controller method is `allow(controller).to receive(:method).and_return(something)`. So I guess omitting `and_return` part could be much like the reason why `current_user` returns `nil`. Also, this is rails 3 syntax. In rails 4 you should use `stub` instead. And another side note: `find_by_id` does not generate an exception when nothing is found, so you won't have to rescue it

Comment: Hey IvanSelivanov, I generated the exception after running into a different problem, every time I ran the server I received an error stating it couldn't find the User with ID =1. Also, I get a deprecation warning when using `stub`. Not sure whats going on there. Do you have an idea what I should `return`? I tried returning `@user` and placing that stub method after creating the `@user`, but still receive the error.

Comment: Why don't you get rid of these stubs for now @Shroy? You can always put them back later, when everything will be working. But for now I suggest making it as simple as possible. I've edited the answer, try this way

Comment: In which environment you get an exception? Development or test? @Shroy