# Logging into application with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, oauth, omniauth

I am trying to test a controller that has authenticated routes. I'm using OmniAuth with Google OAuth2.0. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) on the OmniAuth wiki to set it up for integration testing. However, my test is failing with the following error:

```
1) GroupsController GET #show when user logged in responds with HTTP 200 and a group object
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
       expected the response to have status code 200 but it was 302
     # ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

suggesting that the request is still being redirected.

I've put all the relevant files in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Carpetfizz/5dad0f0f8d5abe79cbe39d6d226cd5e0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem you set `session[:user_id]` in your test.

I *think* you would do that by something like:

```
  RSpec.describe GroupsController, type: :controller do
    describe 'GET #show' do
      context 'when user logged in' do
        it "responds with HTTP 200 and a group object" do
          get :show, {id: 1}, {user_id: 1}
          expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

as the `get` action takes a params hash and a session hash (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451969/rspec-set-session-object)).

You'll also need to create the `User` record so that `User.find` doesn't return nil.

Comment: Also, any reason the [OmniAuth docs](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) didn't mention that? Just wondering if my setup is somehow different from the norm...

Comment: Based on my reading, the OmniAuth instructions are for when you're exercising the authentication flow. In your case, you're not doing that. So, the OmniAuth instructions aren't relevant to your use case.