# Set a session var in Rspec Request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec

I am trying to set a session variable in a request spec.

I have tried the following things to do this:

```
RSpec.describe 'Application Controller' do
  context 'updating an application' do
    before :each do
      @app = create(:application, step: 'investigation')
    end

    it 'should update app status' do
      Status.create(app_id: @app.id, name: Status.names[:start])
      request.session[:app_id] = @app.id
      patch "/applications/start",
            params: s_params
      expect(response).to redirect_to(offers_path)
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried substituting `request` with `@request` both result in the same output.

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
```

then I have tried just setting as:

```
session[:app_id] = @app.id
```

which will yield:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
```

and also setting it like this:

```
patch "/applications/start",
      params: s_params,
      session: {"app_id" => @app.id}
```

which will yield:

```
 ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: session
```

My versions:

```
╰>>> ruby -v
ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x86_64-darwin18]

╰>>> rails -v
Rails 5.2.1

╰>>> rspec -v
RSpec 3.8
  - rspec-core 3.8.0
  - rspec-expectations 3.8.1
  - rspec-mocks 3.8.0
  - rspec-rails 3.8.0
  - rspec-support 3.8.0
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-8/docs/request-specs/request-spec) it suggests we could leverage the sessions but does not give a clear example of how we would do this.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451969/rspec-set-session-object ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried every suggestion they had in that post. I am not inheriting from `ActionController::TestCase` or `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` in my test. 

It also looks like you only have access to the request after making a call to the object, but I need the session to be set before it makes the call.

Comment: Right, sorry. Didn't find anything on the docs to use session directly, but maybe this can help: it seems you can use `cookies['key']` : https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/features/controller_specs/Cookies.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSpec set session object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451969/rspec-set-session-object)

Answer (score 14):

**First of all, little remark...**

I recommend using 'type:' for RSpec test definition. It's good in anyways: easy to determinate by review and we will have the ability to define some extensions/customization for that type of tests(if needed).

**The second point**

We don't have `request` / `response` / `controller` methods(instance) before the request. Only after request, we will have them. By this reason we can't use `request.session[:app_id] = @app.id` before `patch` in your example...

**The third point**

`@app` it is a risky name of variable, not sure it will be a problem or not, but will be better to rename it

**One of the possible solution**

You can try to use some stubs for it, for example:
`allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:session) { { app_id: '11' } }`

**Notes**

The requests methods get / post / patch / and etc are differrent from similar controller test methods. All they are handling by `process` method. More details you can find [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Session.html#method-i-process)

Answer (score -2):

The most straightforward approach that comes into my mind is to mock the controller before doing the request:

```
 session = { app_id: @app.id }
 allow_any_instance_of(SomeController).to receive(:session).and_return(session)

 get some_resources_path
 expect(response).to ...
```

Comment: This does not appear to work in rails 7.0.4.3